# Can the onComplete callback be used with localhost?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I'm using Forge's Design Automation to submit a job and then process its outputs when it is complete. I added onComplete to the activity arguments:

```
"onComplete": {
    "verb": "post",
    "url": `${config.backendServerUrl}/api/forge/da/exampleActivity/onComplete`
}
```

I can confirm that the activity works properly, but the onComplete url is never called. I checked that my server responds to POST requests at the correct URL. I suspect that this might be due to my server configuration using localhost. Is this the case or am I missing something?

Comment: If your server localhost, you need to expose the localhost for Design Automation to send a request.

You can use a tool like https://ngrok.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you might know, Design Automation is running on cloud server. So the call back URL need to be public URL which is reachable from internet.

Regards,
Takehiro